# Resources on how to prevent HTML email errors after it's replied to/forwarded

Tags: html-email

I'm working on an HTML email signature. It displays properly when you send it, but when a recipient replies to or forwards the email, the spacing gets messed up and there are some other problems.

**Before (yay):**
[image]

**After (boo):**
[image]

Here's the code that the signature is generated from:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled</title>
    <!--[if !mso]><!-->
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <!--<![endif]-->

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- 569 when finalizing (don't include px sufix)-->
    <table border-collapse="collapse" width="569" style="border-width: 0; font-family: 'Proxima Nova', Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif; color: #303130;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <!-- Image table -->
          <table border-collapse="collapse" width="83px" align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border:  #ffffff;">
            <tr>
              <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding: 0px; font-family: 'Proxima Nova', Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif;">
                <p style="mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-tablerspace: 0; margin: 0;">
                  <!-- 1. Headshot image (src and alt) -->
                  <img src="http://www.levelfunded.com/email/russ_carpel.jpg" alt="Russ Carpel headshot" style="display: block;"/>
                </p>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <!-- Contact info table -->
          <table border-collapse="collapse" width="329" height="72px" align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="right" style="border:1px solid #ffffff;">
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding: 0px; vertical-align: top; font-family: 'Proxima Nova', Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif;">
                  <p style="mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-tablerspace: 0; margin: 0;">
                    <p style="font-size: 14px; margin: 0px; margin-top: 8px;">
                      <b>
                        <!-- 2. Name -->
                        <span>Russ Carpel</span>
                      </b>
                      <!-- 3. Title -->
                      <span style="font-size: 13px;">CEO</span>

                    </p>
                    <p style="font-size: 14px; margin: 0px; margin-top: 5px;">
                      <!-- 4. Mobile number (href and copy) -->
                      <span><a href="tel:888-888-8888" style="color: #303130; text-decoration: none;">(888) 888-8888</a> m</span>
                      <span style="color: #bababa;"> | </span>
                      <!-- 5. Email (href and copy) -->
                      <span>
                        <a href="mailto:address@domain.com" style="color: #559600; text-decoration: none;">address@domain.com</a>
                      </span>
                      <span>
                        <!-- 6. LinkedIn profile -->
                        &nbsp;
                        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/profile" target="_blank">
                          <img src="http://levelfunded.com/email/linkedIn.jpg" alt="LinkedIn" style="vertical-align: top; margin-top: 1px"/>
                        </a>
                      </span>
                    </p>
                    <p style="font-size: 14px; margin: 0px; margin-top: 5px;">
                      <!-- 7. Office number -->
                      <span><a href="tel:888-888-8888" style="color: #303130; text-decoration: none;">(888) 888-8888</a> o</span>
                      <span style="color: #bababa;"> | </span>
                      <span><a href="http://levelfunded.com" style="color: #559600; text-decoration: none;">levelfunded.com</a></span>
                    </p>
                  </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <!-- Logo table -->
          <table border-collapse="collapse" width="107" height="72px" align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border:1px solid #ffffff;">
            <tr>
              <td bgcolor="#ffffff" valign="bottom" style="font-family: 'Proxima Nova', Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif;">
                <p style="mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-tablerspace: 0; margin: 0;">
                  <a href="http://levelfunded.com" target="_blank">
                    <img src="http://levelfunded.com/email/levelfundedLogoCities.jpg" alt="LevelFunded Logo"/ style="display: block;">
                  </a>
                </p>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
          <!-- Speech carrot table -->
          <table border-collapse="collapse" align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="font-family: 'Proxima Nova', Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif; color: #303130; padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 22px; border-width: 0;">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <img src="http://www.levelfunded.com/email/triangle.jpg" alt="Speech carrot" style="display: block;"/>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <!-- Gray box cell -->
        <td colspan="3" style="padding-left: 8px; padding-top: 8px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; background-color: #e8e8e8;">
          <!-- Video link table -->
          <table border-collapse="collapse" align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="font-family: 'Proxima Nova', Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif; color: #303130; padding-bottom: 8px; padding-right: 8px; border:1px solid #e8e8e8;">
            <tr>
              <td bgcolor="#e8e8e8" style="font-family: 'Proxima Nova', Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif;">
                <p style="mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-tablerspace: 0; margin: 0;">
                  <a href="http://levelfunded.com/video.html">
                    <img src="http://levelfunded.com/email/videoLinkImg-trimmed.jpg" alt="Immediately reduce health benefits costs by $50K, possibly $250K or more. Click to watch video." style="display: block; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;"/>
                  </a>
                </p>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <!-- Article link table -->
          <table border-collapse="collapse" align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="font-family: 'Proxima Nova', Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif; color: #303130; padding-bottom: 8px; padding-right: 8px; border:1px solid #e8e8e8;">
            <tr>
              <td bgcolor="#e8e8e8" style="font-family: 'Proxima Nova', Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif;">
                <p style="mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-tablerspace: 0; margin: 0;">
                  <a href="http://www.chicagotribune.com/business/ct-small-business-insurance-1214-biz-20141214-story.html">
                    <img src="http://levelfunded.com/email/articleLinkImg-trimmed.jpg" alt="Click to read Chicage Tribune article"  style="display: block;"/>
                  </a>
                </p>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
          <table border-collapse="collapse" align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="8" style="font-family: 'Proxima Nova', Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif; color: #7e7e7e; font-size: 10px; line-height: 12px; border-width: 0;">
            <tr>
              <td>
                This email is confidential communication from Level Funded Health Partners LLC and may not be forwarded without the expressed written consent of the company. Level Funded Health Partners LLC is a DE LLC, File #8888888. The company is a U.S. based licensed insurance agency entity. Delaware insurance agency entity license #8888888.
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

I understand that when the recipient composes and sends their reply, their email client has to re-encode the email and that creates the possibility for these formatting errors. (More on that [here](https://emailsignaturerescue.com/support-area/item/why-does-my-email-signature-look-messed-up-or-different-on-reply-emails).)

To be clear, here are the errors I'm talking about:

- Extra space above and below the speech carrot graphic
- Link formatting is lost (on the blurred section, but you can see that the green is turning into blue
- The background color on the gray rectangle is getting dropped
- Padding on the two big graphics is getting decreased
- Font styling on the disclaimer text is getting dropped
- Disclaimer copy is getting truncated after the second # character.

I know trying to answer all of that is too broad. So here's my question:

I've found lots of resources for coding a good html email. However, I haven't been able to find resources on good practices to make it more resilient against these kinds of errors when it is replied to or forwarded. Can anybody point me to any such resources?

Comment: Forwarding emails is always unpredictable, but there are a few errors in your HTML above that should be addressed and tested before resorting to more drastic measures (like investigating wisestamp.com maybe?) Starting: border-collapse="collapse" belongs in the style attribute. Also in the "Contact info table" there are two "align" attributes, and height should be "72". Fix that and try it out. A few notes: Outlook doesn't cascade attributes much of the time, like background colors, so that P tag may be in the way. Outlook also doesn't respect CSS padding/margins. Solution: more complex tables.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't account for all of the different email clients out there with regards to email forwarding. They all handle them differently. You can *almost certainly* count on your HTML formatting being somehow broken when someone forwards an email to someone else with the forward button. (You can do your best though; I commented earlier with some suggestions.)

The alternative is to use a "Forward to a friend" functionality available in some email service providers such as Salesforce (formerly ExactTarget) for example. You would encourage people to click on a link which would take the user to a page to fill in an email address, then the message would be sent to them on the user's behalf. In ET you could also show/hide certain information depending on the context. So, if someone was sending the message via FTAF, any sensitive information could be removed, for example. This all of course depends on your email service provider's offerings.